# Doubts trying to find the Jordan canonical form of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I am reading Gelfand's Lectures in Linear Algebra. I have some questions here:

> [image]
>
> [image]

I am trying to understand how to construct the given vectors with an example:

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -1 & -18 & -7 \\
 1 & -13 & -4 \\
 -1 & 25 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

This matrix has a single eigenvector $(-5, -3, 7)$ and three repeated eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3=-2$.

1. **Questions:** We have $e_1=f_1=g_1=(-5, -3, 7)$, right? Do we have $e_2,f_2,g_2$? I think the answer is "no".

Now I am trying to use this information with the following section of the book:

> [image]

2. **Question:** It's not very clear to me what I should do here. How do I obtain this Jordan block? I think we need to do some change of basis, but it's not clear what change of basis is that.

Comment: 1. No, you have $k = 1$ and $e_1 = \left(-5,-3,7\right)^T$. Gelfand requires the eigenvectors to be linearly independent, so you cannot use one and the same vector three times.

Comment: @darijgrinberg But how should we do, then? Because there is only one eigenvector.

Comment: You need to find $e_2$ and $e_3$. I assume this is explained later on.

Comment: @darijgrinberg In the section about the JNF, it doesn't seems he shows how to construct the other vectors. The construction of the other vectors seems to be what he calls "elementary divisors". Is that correct?

Comment: I think he constructs them in §19. But I have never read that book, so I'm not sure. [Better scan, by the way](http://libgen.rs/book/index.php?md5=F231B7C2E2FF14E6597EB3378B61E003) (can be quite useful with the many subscripts).